# MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter fails to convert json to entity

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate, jackson2

I am using spring boot. RestTemplate. MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter

MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter fails to convert following json to entity. It does not throw any error. I am trying to debug the same. Whats wrong with Json ? and how do I enable failure for MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter

```
    {
      "id" : 1,
      "context" : "MYC",
      "my_date" : "2021-06-20",
      "files" : [ {
        "file_name" : "here.txt",
        "created_time" : "2021-06-20T12:00:00+02:00"
      } ]
    }
```

Entity setter/getter are present

```
    public class Details{
    
        private Long id;
    
        private LocalDate myDate;
    
        private ContextEnum context;
    
        private List<FileInfo> files;
    }
public class FileInfo {
    private String fileName;

    private OffsetDateTime createdTime;

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume it is because of JSON key are `Snake Case` but class field names in `Camel Case`. You can fixed this by three ways,

1. Rename field names to match JSON object
2. Annotate setter methods with `@JsonProperty` annotation.
3. Annotate classes with `@JsonNaming` annotation

#### Method 2

```
public class Details{
    private Long id;
    private LocalDate myDate;
    private ContextEnum context;
    private List<FileInfo> files;

    @JsonProperty("my_date")
    public void setMyDate(LocalDate myDate) {
        this.myDate = myDate;
    }
}

public class FileInfo {
    private String fileName;
    private OffsetDateTime createdTime;

    @JsonProperty("file_name")
    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    @JsonProperty("created_time")
    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }
}
```

#### Method 3

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
public class Details{
    private Long id;
    private LocalDate myDate;
    private ContextEnum context;
    private List<FileInfo> files;
}

@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
public class FileInfo {
    private String fileName;
    private OffsetDateTime createdTime;

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't realise i was customizing MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter in one of my configuration.